# How can I disable a clickable Switch inside TouchableOpacity?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app I have a line of text and adjutant to it on the same row is a switch. Clicking the switch changes its value but I would like the whole row to be clickable and change its value.

I ended up with this code using `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => {this.setState({isAgree: !this.state.isAgree})}>
     <Text>Do you agree? </Text>
     <Switch value={this.state.isAgree} onValueChange={(n) => this.setState({isAgree: n})}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The row is clickable and does what it should, but when clicking the `Switch` the press event is disregarded by the `TouchableOpacity` and this way I am getting two different "effects" - standard `TouchableOpacity` click event when pressing anywhere but the switch and a standard `Switch` click event when pressing the switch itself.

I tried setting `disabled={true}` on the switch and it gives the exact behavior I'm looking for - except the switch is dimmed out. Playing around with `zIndex` or removing `onValueChange` also doesn't help.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Is the problem just the feedback behavior of touching the element? I mean, when you click on the text you see the opacity change and, instead, clicking on switch doesn't have this effect...?

Comment: @Milore Exactly. I'd like clicking anywhere in the TouchableOpacity to have the same effect and "animation"

Comment: It's a nice question and unfortunately I do not have a real solution. On Android using `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` instead of `<TouchableOpacity>` is ok, 'cause you have no feedback pressing the text and the same animation on the switch. On iOS btw it seems a bit different: touching the text does not trigger the animation, 'cause the switch value is set externally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create this behavior by wrapping a `View` with `pointerEvents="none"` around your `Switch`.

The `pointerEvents="none"` prevents the Switch event from firing. Instead the parent event (the TouchableOpacity's onPress), will be fired.

```
   <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => {this.setState({isAgree: !this.state.isAgree})}}>
   <Text>Do you agree? </Text>
   <View pointerEvents="none">
    <Switch value={this.state.isAgree} onValueChange={(n) => this.setState({isAgree: n})}/>
   </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This achieves exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect to make only the text clickable while the switch retain its normal behaviour. if that is the case

change your code like this:

```
<View style={flexDirection:'row'}>
<TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => {this.setState({isAgree: !this.state.isAgree})}>
     <Text>Do you agree? </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
     <Switch value={this.state.isAgree} onValueChange={(n) => this.setState({isAgree: n})}/>
</View>
```

Comment: No - as stated I would like both text and switch to act as one, your code produces the exact result as the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the value as a status value so that can change it.

can you try this code?

```js
this.state={
      check: false
}
...
 <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => {this.setState({ check:true })}}>
     <Text>Do you agree? </Text>
     <Switch value={this.state.isAgree} onValueChange={(n) => this.setState({isAgree: n})} disabled={this.state.check}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what this achieves - The switch is enabled at first and is clickable by itself and not as part of the surrounding TouchableOpacity + after clicking the text the switch becomes disabled which is also not something desired

Comment: Don't you want the switch to be disabled when you press something other than the switch?